# Azure devops publicly reusable YAML

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml

I was trying to set up a YAML that anyone can extend and reuse. I found a way to reuse pipelines across repositories using `resources` and 'repository' in the YAML file. It is something like this:

```
resources:
  repositories:
   - repository: templates
     type: git/github
     name: username/reponame
     endpoint: ???
```

This seems to work across repositories. However, it makes the `endpoint` property mandatory. This doesn't seem to make sense. The process of extending the YAML is read-only and the repository could be public-facing. Why would it be mandatory to specify an endpoint for authorization? Is there another way? Maybe to extend a YAML through the raw URL.

Answer (score 1):

> The process of extending the YAML is read-only and the repository could be public-facing. Why would it be mandatory to specify an endpoint for authorization?

It depends on your repository type.

As the document [Resources: repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-repositories):

> Type Pipelines support the following values for the repository type:
>   `git`, `github`, `githubenterprise`, and `bitbucket`. The git type refers to
>   Azure Repos Git repos.

And the state of the endpoint:

> endpoint: string  # name of the service connection to use (**for types
>   that aren't Azure Repos**)

So, if the type of repository is `Git`, the endpoint property is **not** mandatory.

As test, following script yaml works fine:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Testproject
    type: git
    name: MyTestProject/Testproject
```

But, if the type of repository is not git, like `github`, `bitbucket`, we need create a **Service connections** for authorization. So, we have to specify the endpoint:  for authorization.

Hope this helps.

Comment: THANKS! it kind of help. still doesn't explain why githug would need authorization. it can still be a public repo

Comment: @NevilleNazerane, Sorry, I may not have explained this clearly. As I said finally, we need to create a Service connection. The current Service connection template only has a unified template that requires authentication, and there are no additional templates that do not require authentication. If you want to build a public github repo, you can try to fork that repo. For the service connection without authentication, you could add this feature to the MS team. Have a nice day!

Comment: Sorry, I was just about to try this and realize it doesn't really resolve the issue, so had to unaccept it. The link you posted also mentions it would only work under the current organization. There is no option mentioned to set the organization. Hence it isn't really "public-facing" solution